# Laravel reponses giving incorrect code 200 instead of 401

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having issues trying to get Laravel (5.8) to return a 401 HTTP status code.

Route (api.php)

```
route::get('test','testController@test');
```

Controller

```
public function test(){

   return response("error",401)->header('Content-Type','text/plain');

   // Also not working.
   // header("Content-Type: test/plain", 401);
   // print "error";
   // exit();
}
```

The result I am getting is a 200 instead the desired 401. I also test the plain PHP way with `header()` and terminate the execution with `exit()`, but no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ensure all your caches are cleared before testing. If the native PHP code doesn't even work, consider that you're looking at the wrong route or method.

Comment: Cache is clear, the route is correct because I see the ***error*** printed on the screen. This project is small have no more than 10 routes. and I still getting a 200 response.

Comment: How are you testing/checking the response?

Comment: `$resp = response("error", 401)->header("Content-Type", "text/plain"); dd($resp);`

Comment: I am using postman and apache logs.

Comment: You are probably omiting relevant pieces of code here. The code you posted work's on a blank Laravel project. So your project have something wrong.

Comment: Are you requesting your url from postman with the: `Accept: application/json` header? If not try to make the request with that header